# Can QGIS handle *.adf raster attribute data?

Tags: qgis, esri-grid-format

I have been trying to open Esri grid format (*.adf) files in QGIS. I can display the raster set itself, however, the appropriate attribute data fails to join the spatial dataset.

Can QGIS display the full source raster for ArcGIS?

Or is it a 'proprietary' format that can only be fully displayed in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Qgis uses [gdal](/questions/tagged/gdal) to access .adf rasters, Arcinfo Binary Grids (note: .adf files are also used for Arcinfo vectors).  Reading the reverse engineered [Arc/Info Binary Grid Format description](http://home.gdal.org/projects/aigrid/aigrid_format.html) page one sees

> **vat.adf:** This relates to the value attribute table. This is the table
>   corresponding integer raster values with a set of attributes. I
>   presume it is really just a pointer into info in a manner similar to
>   the pat.adf file in a vector coverage, but I haven't investigated yet.

So, no Qgis probably can't read Arcinfo raster attributes. That document was written a long time ago though, so perhaps things have changed.

I don't have access to a vat-enabled raster right now so can't test, but I surmise the structure outlined in the [Raster dataset attribute tables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_dataset_attribute_tables/009t00000009000000/) Arcgis help is likely quite similar to the vat.adf structure, for those wishing to plug the hole in the format description and perhaps extend the gdal [aigrid](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/frmts/aigrid/) format driver.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you coming to this question in 2022 there is now a QGIS plugin funded by NOAA called **Raster Attribute Table Plugin** that allows you to load the attribute table and stylize your layer by the classes defined in the table.

Comment: ...and how do I add .adf files using the plugin???